# Git pull or push results in fatal error but is valid branch

Tags: git

This is my structure

local branches:

```
master
devel 
feature 

remote branches
master
devel
feature
```

I am in my local branch `feature` and i would like to push to local `devel`.

I ran `git push devel` but it throws up a fatal error. Not a git repository

But i ran `git checkout devel` and it switches to the `devel` branch.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to push the local branch `feature` to another local branch `devel`.  If you intend to push local `feature` to *remote* `devel`, then you should use:

```
git push origin feature:devel
```

More typically, you would be pushing `feature` to its remote counterpart `feature`, in which case you would use:

```
git push origin feature
```

As for your error, when you ran

```
git push devel
```

it looks like Git interpreted `devel` as the name of a remote, rather than the name of the remote branch.  The general syntax is:

```
git push <remote-name> <remote branch name>
```

Comment: I wanted to push to local devel as this branch has the code that was the same as the remote devel branch. So pushing it to ensure it works before I push my update changes to my remote devel branch

Answer (score 1):

Though it's possible to push a local branch to another local branch, via `git push . feature:devel`, it's not the expected operation. You can use `git merge` to manipulate local branches.

```
git checkout devel
git merge feature
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `git push origin HEAD:devel` is what you need, where "origin" should be replaced by the name of the remote as you see in `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin branch1:branch2
```

may be you can use PULL

```
git checkout devel
```

then

```
git pull feature
```

Comment: are you ready run `git commit -m "bla bla bla"` first then then `git push origin feature:devel` . its work for me